# Concurrence in higher dimensions?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

Does anybody know of any calculation of the concurrence for some mixed state other than the [qubit-qubit case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrence_%28quantum_computing%29) (which was solved by Wootters)?

Comment: In a related question, does anybody know of "efficient" numerical algorithms to actually do the numerical optimization associated with the calculation of the concurrence for a mixed density matrix (other than for the qubit-qubit case)?

Answer (score 1):

This has been extended for pure states of arbitrary dimensions (aka multi-qudit pure states) in a very intuitive way by looking at the geometry of the tensor products with increasing dimensionality. A pedagogic explanation to reach the generalization from the basic notion of separability may be found in our recent article here: [arXiv:1607.00164 (2016)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.00164).

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE and thank you for your contribution :) Would you consider writing a short short summary of the key idea of the article linked (and maybe author&title)? This way, even in the unlikely event of arXiv-failure, people will still be able to know what to look for.

Comment: Dear Vineeth Bhaskara: Welcome to Phys.SE. Are you in any way related to the author of the linked article? For your information, Physics.SE has a [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/582/2451) that it is OK to cite oneself, but it should be stated clearly and explicitly in the answer itself, not in attached links.

Answer (score -2):

It is unlikely that there would be such a calculation, because there exists a [proof](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/16/3/033027/meta) that quantum discord is computationally intractable. As a consequence, the calculation of most entanglement measures would be NP-hard or even NP-complete. Apparently, distillable entanglement is an exception, but I'm not aware of any measure that gives the exact distillable entanglement of a state. The negativity only give an upper bound.